# Looking for voice command code/library for obj-c/c

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, voice

C/Obj-C Developers- I am looking for a way to listen for a specific word or small set of words to be spoken and fire an event. Needs to be able to run on the iPhone/iPad ... Looking for ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a few commercial options, but from what I can find no (Easy) free method. Searching around seems to indicate that Julius ( http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php ) could work for iPhone, but there aren't any instructions I can find.

Commercial:
* Creaceed